# What is the fastest way to send data from one thread to another in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, low-latency

I have tried an experiment where I built a simple Producer/Consumer program. They run in separate threads. The producer generates some data and the consumer picks it up in another thread. The messaging latency I achieved is approximately 100 nano seconds. Can anybody tell me if this is reasonable or are there significantly faster implementations out there?

I'm not using locks ... just simple memory counters. My experiment is described here:

http://tradexoft.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/how-to-move-data-between-threads-in-100-nanoseconds/

Basically the consumer waits on a counter to be incremented and then it calls the handler function. So not much code really. Still I was surprised it took 100ns.

The consumer looks like this:

```
 void operator()()
    {
      while (true)
      {
        while (w_cnt==r_cnt) {};
        auto rc=process_data(data);
        r_cnt++;
        if (!rc)
          break;
      }
    }
```

The producer simply incremnts w_cnt when it has data available.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: And how exactly did you *measure* this 100 ns latency? Don't forget to take into account measurement bias. Also, using this type of user-space "spin lock" is extremely bad for your overall performance.

Comment: I find a 100ns measurement by itself already vague...

Comment: tA = Perform a for-loop over 10K mem operations; tB = Perform a for-loop over 10K empty loops; tA - tB = cumulated time for 10K elements without the loop overhead. tmem = (tA - tB)/10K;

Comment: also the latency depends on what are you doing and what is the purpose of your service, and as consequence what is the crucial part that suffers from what you define as "latency", for example you can reduce latency in a service introducing a cache, like in the DNS/NS world. So you keep the underlaying application basically the same and only add a memory space as cache.

Comment: 'I was surprised it took 100ns' - me too.  That seems very short indeed for inter-thread comms, even when, presumably, wasting almost a complete core on polling.

Comment: Inter-thread comms works well when the operations performed on the data transferred take much longer than the comms latency, eg. when queueing pointers to large network/disk buffers.  If the operations on the communicated data take ns, rather than ms, then you are pretty well stuft.

Comment: What are your reasons for requiring synchronisation better than 100ns?

Comment: I measured it at about 100ns by passing 500e6 messages from the producer to consumer, then divided the total elapsed time by 500e6. Both threads are busy waiting of course.

Comment: If every producer consumer scheme is implemented using busy wait, computers will melt.

Answer (score 6):

I imagine your latency is a product of how the operating system schedules context-switching, rather than the spin lock itself, and I doubt you can do much about it.

You can, however, move more data at once by using a ring buffer.  If one thread writes and one thread reads, you can implement a ring buffer without locks.  Essentially it would be the same spin-lock approach (waiting until `tailidx != headidx`), but the producer could pump more than a single value into the buffer before it is switched out to the consumer.  That ought to improve your overall latency (but not your single-value latency).

Comment: I like the ring-buffer idea. Are there any reference implementations in C++? I'm aware of the Java Disruptor but can't quite figure out exactly how they did it. There isn't any context switching in my current producer/consumer implementation as far as I know. Both threads are busy waiting.

Comment: If you search for "ring buffer" or "circular queue" and include keywords like "C++" you should find plenty of code.  Really, it's such a simple concept that you hardly need to.  Create a fixed-size array, define a head and a tail index, and just go for it.  The `push` advances the tail while the `pop` advances the head.  You do a modulo by the array size of course.  And you need to be careful not to fill the very last element (such that `head == tail`) because that state is already used to say the queue is empty.

Comment: got it ... a bounded queue essentially ... however I will need to use a spin lock (TAS or CAS) if I have multiple producers correct? (I already have something like that but the q is unbounded ... ) Is there a way to use the ring buffer with user level locks only?

Comment: This only works without locks if you have at most two threads where one always writes and the other always reads, which seems to be the problem you were trying to address.  Why do you need such fast synchronisation?  What is it that you are doing?

Comment: I have a trading system that's somewhat latency sensitive. Just want to make sure I have the fastest (within reason) implementation possible. There is quite a bit of thread-to-thread (actor-to-actor) messaging. I'm fine I think with my current latencies (about 700ns thread to thread) but if I can reduce that would be great.

Comment: I don't know how real-time you need to be, but when you are dealing with events happening at a particular time you can often run "behind the clock" by stamping messages with the actual event time.  It's well and good to respond in sub-millisecond time, but what other latencies are there in your system?  For example, do you then fire packets at a web service to respond to trading prices?  If you do, then 0.7us lag is surely irrelevant. If it would take 100ms to actually respond, then squabbling over less than 0.001 percent of that is pretty silly. That number is purely illustrative, of course.

Comment: good example of ring-buffer is boost spsc_queue. i measured it in my question and the result is 300 ns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507669/fastest-possible-way-to-pass-data-from-one-thread-to-another

Answer (score 3):

If your threads are executed on different cores, then the fastest way to "send message" from one thread to another is [write barrier(sfence)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).

When you write to some memory location, you actually write to the [processors write buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_buffer), not to the main-memory location. Write buffer is periodically flushed to main memory by the processor. Also, write instruction can be delayed when instruction reordering occurs. When actual write to main memory occurs, cache coherency protocol comes into play and "informs" another processor about memory location update. After that, another processor invalidates cache line and another thread will be able to see your changes.

Store barrier force processor to flush write buffer and prohibit instruction reordering and your program will be able to send more messages per second.